# htaccess block access from a top level domain?

Tags: linux, .htaccess

Is there a way through htaccess to block access to images from my site when requested by a specific top level domain, eg ".ru"?

I currently use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^\.ru [NC,OR]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png [r=307,NC]
```

but dont think its working as intended..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression that you are using, `^\.ru`, means "**anything that STARTS with `.ru`**", so if the referer is `http://some-site.ru/some-path/some-page.html`, it's obviously not going to match. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://[^/]+\.ru/? [NC]
```

Comment: hmm nope that actually redirected all to to the google logo (should only do so when referer is from a .ru domain...

Comment: @JohnAnderson You need to get rid of the `OR` flag, it's essentially saying that the condition is optional.

Comment: Thanks got it now (finally)!